# Remove need for Github Personal access tokens for push authentication

Tags: git, github, push, access-token, commit

I have a Github account with Personal access tokens setup in Developer Settings.

I would like to revert back to just needing to use the Github password for push authentication.

Does anyone know where the option is to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you can continue to use a password instead of a token as long as you aren't using two-factor authentication.  You can just switch; there's no configuration needed.  If you're using two-factor authentication, using a password isn't possible.

Note however that GitHub is moving away from allowing Basic authentication with your account password.  Users who use their account password for API access and Git LFS access are receiving notifications that this will no longer be allowed.

Using a personal access token is much more secure because (a) you can restrict a token to only certain scopes and (b) it can't be used to authenticate in the web interface or change your password.  Additionally, because it's randomly generated, it isn't vulnerable to brute-forcing.

#### UPDATE: This option is not available since August, 2021

Go to settings -> Personal tokens -> create token (fine-grained or classic) -> choose your permissions and enter a name -> copy the token and use it as your password.